# Problem with jquery.ui.autocomplete.js on IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Here is the code. IE7 spouts an "'active.0' is null or not an object" error on line 39, which is:

```
input.trigger("activate.autocomplete", [$.data(active[0], "originalObject")]); $("body").trigger("off.autocomplete");
```

Works perfectly in Firefox/Chrome/Opera. Any ideas? Many thanks and much appreciated.

```
/* jQuery Autocomplete
 * Version 1.0
 * Written by Yehuda Katz (wycats@gmail.com) and Rein Henrichs (reinh@reinh.com)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2, jQuery dimensions plugin
 *
 * Copyright 2007 Yehuda Katz, Rein Henrichs
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   hxxp://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     *   hxxp://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 */

/*
 * @description Form autocomplete plugin using preloaded or Ajax JSON data source 
 *
 * @example $('input#user-name').autocomplete({list: ["quentin", "adam", "admin"]})
 * @desc Simple autocomplete with basic JSON data source
 *
 * @example $('input#user-name').autocomplete({ajax: "/usernames.js"})
 * @desc Simple autocomplete with Ajax loaded JSON data source
 *
 */


(function($) {

  $.ui = $.ui || {}; $.ui.autocomplete = $.ui.autocomplete || {}; var active;

  $.fn.autocompleteMode = function(container, input, size, opt) { 
    var original = input.val(); var selected = -1; var self = this;

    $.data(document.body, "autocompleteMode", true);

    $("body").one("cancel.autocomplete", function() { 
      input.trigger("cancel.autocomplete"); $("body").trigger("off.autocomplete"); input.val(original); 
    });

    $("body").one("activate.autocomplete", function() {
      input.trigger("activate.autocomplete", [$.data(active[0], "originalObject")]); $("body").trigger("off.autocomplete");
    });

    $("body").one("off.autocomplete", function(e, reset) {
      container.remove();
      $.data(document.body, "autocompleteMode", false);
      input.unbind("keydown.autocomplete");
      $("body").add(window).unbind("click.autocomplete").unbind("cancel.autocomplete").unbind("activate.autocomplete");
    });

    // If a click bubbles all the way up to the window, close the autocomplete
    $(window).bind("click.autocomplete", function() { $("body").trigger("cancel.autocomplete"); });

    var select = function() {
      active = $("> *", container).removeClass("active").slice(selected, selected + 1).addClass("active");
      input.trigger("itemSelected.autocomplete", [$.data(active[0], "originalObject")]);     
      input.val(opt.insertText($.data(active[0], "originalObject")));
    };

    container.mouseover(function(e) {
      // If you hover over the container, but not its children, return
      if(e.target == container[0]) return;
      // Set the selected item to the item hovered over and make it active
      selected = $("> *", container).index($(e.target).is('li') ? $(e.target)[0] : $(e.target).parents('li')[0]); select();
    }).bind("click.autocomplete", function(e) {
      $("body").trigger("activate.autocomplete"); $.data(document.body, "suppressKey", false); 
    });

    input
      .bind("keydown.autocomplete", function(e) {
        if(e.which == 27) { $("body").trigger("cancel.autocomplete"); }
        else if(e.which == 13) { $("body").trigger("activate.autocomplete"); }
        else if(e.which == 40 || e.which == 9 || e.which == 38) {
          switch(e.which) {
            case 40: 
            case 9:
              selected = selected >= size - 1 ? 0 : selected + 1; break;
            case 38:
              selected = selected <= 0 ? size - 1 : selected - 1; break;
            default: break;
          }
          select();
        } else { return true; }
        $.data(document.body, "suppressKey", true);
      });
  };

  $.fn.autocomplete = function(opt) {

    opt = $.extend({}, {
      timeout: 1000,
      getList: function(input) { input.trigger("updateList", [opt.list]); },
      template: function(str) { return "<li>" + opt.insertText(str) + "</li>"; },
      insertText: function(str) { return str; },
      match: function(typed) { return this.match(new RegExp(typed)); },
      wrapper: "<ul class='jq-ui-autocomplete'></ul>"
    }, opt);

    if($.ui.autocomplete.ext) {
      for(var ext in $.ui.autocomplete.ext) {
        if(opt[ext]) {
          opt = $.extend(opt, $.ui.autocomplete.ext[ext](opt));
          delete opt[ext];
        }
    } }

    return this.each(function() {

      $(this)
        .keypress(function(e) {
          var typingTimeout = $.data(this, "typingTimeout");
          if(typingTimeout) window.clearInterval(typingTimeout);

          if($.data(document.body, "suppressKey"))
            return $.data(document.body, "suppressKey", false);
          else if($.data(document.body, "autocompleteMode") && e.charCode < 32 && e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46) return false;          
          else {
            $.data(this, "typingTimeout", window.setTimeout(function() { 
              $(e.target).trigger("autocomplete"); 
            }, opt.timeout));
          }
        })
        .bind("autocomplete", function() {
          var self = $(this);

          self.one("updateList", function(e, list) {
            list = $(list)
              .filter(function() { return opt.match.call(this.toLowerCase(), self.val()); })
              .map(function() {
                var node = $(opt.template(this))[0];
                $.data(node, "originalObject", this);
                return node; 
              });

            $("body").trigger("off.autocomplete");

            if(!list.length) return false;

            var container = list.wrapAll(opt.wrapper).parents(":last").children();

            var offset = self.offset();

            opt.container = container
              .css({top: offset.top + self.outerHeight(), left: offset.left, width: self.width()})
              .appendTo("body");

            $("body").autocompleteMode(container, self, list.length, opt);
          });

          opt.getList(self);
        });

    });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

http://github.com/istruble/jquery-autocomplete/commit/bdc926bd2c18c3ebab4e31463a8ae899fd761316#diff-1

It is a version of jquery.ui.autocomplete.js with most of the IE 7 issues fixed. I found a few more issues which I listed at the bottom along with how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that works javascript first:

```
$(".student_search").autocomplete("student_search.php", {
                minChars: 2,
                cacheLength: 20,
                matchContains: true,
                highlightItem: true,
                parse: function(data) {
                            return $.map(eval(data), function(row) {
                                return {
                                        data: row,
                                        value: row.studentname, //value being searched for
                                        result: row.studentidnumber //value in text input
                                        }
                            });
                },
                formatItem: function(row, i, max, term) {
                    return "<span style='font-size: 110%;'>" + row.studentname + "</span><br/>" + "ID: " + row.studentidnumber + ", " + " Grade: " + row.studentgradenumber;
                            },
                formatResult: function(row, i, max){
                    return row.studentidnumber;
                }
        });
```

});

Here is the code in the PHP file. It prints a JSON object with the data.

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
require_once("php/mysql.connect.php");
$request = strtolower($_GET['q']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    CONCAT(studentfname, ' ', studentlname, '') 
                        AS studentname, studentidnumber, 
                            CONCAT(studentgradenumber, 'th') 
                                AS studentgradenumber
                                    FROM studentinfo
                                        WHERE studentlname LIKE '%".$request."%'
                                            OR studentfname LIKE '%".$request."%'
                                                OR studentidnumber LIKE '%".$request."%'") or die(mysql_error());

$results = array();

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //fetch each result using the column name as the array key
{
  foreach($row as $column=>$val) //loop through each column
  {
    $results[$i][$column] = $val; //build array using incremental row # and column name
  }
  $i++; //increase the row counter
}       
print json_encode($results);
}
```

The JSON object that is printed is:

```
[{"studentname":"Joe Schmo","studentidnumber":"123456","studentgradenumber":"11th"}]
```

so row.studentname returns Joe Schmo. Where row is the name of the variable in the function and studentname is the name of the key from the JSON object.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with autocompletion of jquery ui version 1.8.9 and IE7. I use 1.8.16 now and it works.