# jquery autocomplete ie bug

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I have bassistance jquery-plugin-autocomplete setup and working fine for FF and chrome but with IE there is a strange behaviour. If I select an option with the arrow+ enter key the result gets selected and treated as choosen (->input box and submit form) but if I select with the mouse and and the active-css is applied it does not work (on click the result window just dissapear) AND if I click fast so that the CSS does not yet apply it works. I tried the bgiframe after reading some posts but I think this problem is different.

Have anyone met this problem and know how to fix it.

(I do not put any code since I do not demand anyone to try to bugfix a jquery plugin, rather just see if somebody met and fixed this problem themselves and can share)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with the autocomplete in jquery-ui 1.8.6, which has taken over the development of the bassistance plugin. After upgrading to the latest version (1.8.16 at the time of writing) the problem was solved. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267200/problem-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete-js-on-ie7/7671681#7671681) led me in the right direction.

As you're still using the bassistance version, which is depricated, I would suggest upgrading to the latest jquery-ui version.